# Intentionally use both latex- and oil-based paints in a room?

Tags: painting, oil-based-paint

I recently learned that latex-based paint does not bond well to oil-based paint without some extra prepping first.  Is there any reason not to exploit this feature, by using oil-based paint on the ceiling & trim, and latex-based on the walls?

The idea is that, if you are careful with your cutting in the first time, during future applications the cutting in can go quicker, and you could possibly forego taping edges, etc.

Comment: Latex won't stick if you want it to, and it will stick if you don't want it to. ;-)

Comment: Depends on the paint. Some oil based primers will allow latex to stick, plus newer acrylic based paints will usually stick to oil as well. And vice versa. Just depends on the paint.

Comment: That would involve intentionally using oil based paint - which I avoid like the plague, having no desire to screw around with all the charming solvent waste that generates...and not sticking well does not in any way mean that you can be sloppy cutting in the next time - just that it will make a peeling mess.